# Disable special (foreign) characters wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, fonts

Is there a way for me to disable chars like حنان in wordpress ? I tried searching for a plugin to do this but i was unsuccesfull.. Maybe i can do something with the char type ?

Comment: You can disable it with char type in the wp-config - but if there is such chars on your site, wordpress just wont be able to read them probably - it will just display weird chars instead - why would you need to do so?

Comment: I would like to block this because people keep putting them on t-shirts we need to print https://www.shirt-discounter.nl/winkel/clothing/polos/bedrukte-polo-met-eigen-ontwerp/?customize